# Moving a picturebox with visual basic

Tags: basic

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Location.X + TextBox1.Text, PictureBox1.Location.Y) 'Timer run from left to right to the number of input
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make it go left instead of right with a stopping point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216068/how-do-i-make-it-go-left-instead-of-right-with-a-stopping-point)

Comment: What is your question?